# Use a Mac Mini as an Apple TV For Audio?

Tags: iphone, audio, mac-mini, appletv, airplay

On the weekend I went to a friend's house, he owns an Apple TV. He started streaming music from the Music Apple application on the phone to the Apple TV, and on the TV it appears the song lyrics appeared while playing the song.

I was wondering if I could do the same with my setup. I have a TV and a Mac mini connected to the TV. I can send the music through the phone, but I am not sure if I can get the same image as if I have an Apple TV. It would be great if I could do that. Also, it would be great if the phone is not sending the music through airplay, just getting the music from the computer without needing to get the music from the phone; this would be for performance.